# Why node's position in SceneKit inconsistent?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm writing App using SceneKit with physics simulation, and want to get the precise position of node at every rendering loop.
But there seems to be curious gap between the position which physics simulation computes.

In `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: TimeInterval)`, I've put these code to see the amount the node moves and the velocity of physicsBody.
(I'm only interested in horizontal position so calculating only x/z position)

```
let distance = sqrtf(powf(position.x - previous.x, 2) + powf(position.z - previous.z, 2))
let velocity = sqrtf(powf(node.physicsBody!.velocity.x, 2) + powf(node.physicsBody!.velocity.z, 2))

print("distance: \(distance), velocity: \(velocity), fps: \(1 / timeDelta)")
```

the output is

```
distance: 4.0241585, velocity: 120.8824, fps: 59.969265810462744
distance: 4.0241585, velocity: 120.882034, fps: 59.96926570579626
distance: 4.0241585, velocity: 120.881676, fps: 59.969265810462744
distance: 4.0257597, velocity: 120.88132, fps: 59.96926570579626
distance: 4.0257597, velocity: 120.88095, fps: 59.969265810462744  <--
distance: 2.0128798, velocity: 120.88059, fps: 59.96926570579626   <--
distance: 2.0144815, velocity: 120.880226, fps: 59.96926570579626
distance: 2.0144815, velocity: 120.879875, fps: 59.969265810462744
distance: 2.0167186, velocity: 120.87951, fps: 59.96926570579626
```

`<--` indicates the distance between previous rendering loop and next become suddenly **half** even the velocity of physicsBody remains almost same. (And fps also remains same)

Can anyone explain why this occurs and how to fix?
Or how to get the position of node precisely with physics simulation?

**UPDATE**

As I change `scene.physicsWorld.speed = 0.9` it becomes more smoother.
Not meaning it becomes consistent but the moving amount change cycle become short as below.

```
distance: 3.182204, velocity: 118.95072, fps: 59.969265810462744
distance: 2.9860368, velocity: 119.00602, fps: 59.96926570579626
distance: 2.7921088, velocity: 119.06052, fps: 59.969265810462744
distance: 2.5959413, velocity: 119.11419, fps: 59.96926570579626
distance: 2.4004152, velocity: 119.167046, fps: 59.96926570579626
distance: 2.202648, velocity: 119.219086, fps: 59.969265810462744
distance: 2.0064793, velocity: 119.270325, fps: 59.96926570579626
distance: 1.8064706, velocity: 119.270325, fps: 59.969265810462744
distance: 3.5972602, velocity: 119.3206, fps: 59.96926570579626
distance: 3.4010928, velocity: 119.37006, fps: 59.969265810462744
distance: 3.2049258, velocity: 119.41873, fps: 59.96926570579626
distance: 3.007158, velocity: 119.466606, fps: 59.96926570579626
```

Seems not best work around but better.

Comment: Are you getting the position using node.presentation.position?

Comment: yes, and tried node.position too but same things happened